# Running Background Jobs in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, background, jobs, abp

I'm using the Angular Module Zero template (https://aspnetzero.com/) and have a simple background job that implements the default BackgroundJob class. Problem is that when this runs in our kubernetes environment each one of our pods picks up the job and runs it resulting in duplicate entries in our database. What is the correct way of handling background jobs in the Module Zero template when hosted in kubernetes?

Comment: Are you saying you dont want parallel jobs? If you do, it sounds like your app itself needs to manage multi-reader pattern of the work queue

Comment: No I don't want parallel jobs. The problem is that the same job is running on each pod in parallel.